# JavaScript - Getter/Setter in Objects's Prototype is not working. Getter returns last element

Tags: javascript, prototype, getter-setter, last-modified

I am new to JavaScript. While working with given javascript, I'm expecting the output values as "123"; "test1"; "456" and "test2", as there are two instances.

But the returned values are "456";"test2"; "456" and "test2".

If I Change the setter to work on "this" (Which is currently coomented out in code), the problem resolves. I am unable to understand why protype object is behaving diffrently.

I don't want to declare the variables with this, as i want variables to be private, which can be accessed only through getter/setters method.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function Test(){
    var name;
    var id;


    Test.prototype.setId = function(newId){
        id = newId; 
    }

    //this.id = function(newId){
    Test.prototype.getId = function(newId){
        return  id;
    }


    Test.prototype.setName = function(newName){
        name = newName; 
    }

    //this.getName = function(newGuid){
    Test.prototype.getName = function(newGuid){
        return name;    
    }


}



function callme(){
    var instance1 = new Test();
    instance1.setId("123");
    instance1.setName("test1");
    var instance2 = new Test();
    instance2.setId("456");
    instance2.setName("test2");
    alert(instance1.getId());
    alert(instance1.getName());
    alert(instance2.getId());
    alert(instance2.getName());
}


</script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick='callme()'> Test </button>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I have changed my code, as per the suggestion of Matt given below. But the code is not working with inheritance. I modified the code as follows. The current implementation creates the object of derived type and tries to call the methods of base class.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

(function () {
    var stores = [];
    var counter = 0;
    Test = function () {
        this.storeId = stores.length;
        stores.push({});
    }

    Test.prototype.setGuid = function (newId) {
        stores[this.storeId].id = newId;
    }
    Test.prototype.getGuid = function (newId) {
        return stores[this.storeId].id;
    }
    Test.prototype.setName = function (newName) {
        stores[this.storeId].name = newName;
    }
    Test.prototype.getName = function (newGuid) {
        return stores[this.storeId].name;
    }
})();

Derived.prototype = new Test();
Derived.prototype.constructor = Derived

function Derived(){
    Test();//call to base class
    //some additional method
}


function callme(){
    var instance1 = new Derived();
    instance1.setGuid("123");
    instance1.setName("test1");

    var instance2 = new Derived();
    instance2.setGuid("456");
    instance2.setName("test2");

    alert(instance1.getName());
    alert(instance1.getGuid());

    alert(instance2.getName());
    alert(instance2.getGuid());



}


</script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick='callme()'> Test </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Secondly, I am unsure about clearing the memory from `stores` variable when the variable is cleared up (goes out of scope).

Answer (score 5):

Your properties are global. You must use `this` to refer to the properties of the instance.

Fix your code like this :

```
function Test(){
    this.name =''; // this only to show that the property exist,
                   //  it doesn't change the behavior as you set it later
    this.id='';
}

Test.prototype.setId = function(newId){
    this.id = newId; 
}

Test.prototype.getId = function(){
    return this.id;
}


Test.prototype.setName = function(newName){
    this.name = newName; 
}

Test.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;    
}
```

I fixed a few other problems, among them the fact you shouldn't declare an argument in `getX` as you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.

I don't want to use this, as I want variable name and id to be private.

Else these variables can be accessed even without getter/setters.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the prototype methods every time you create a new instance - so the variable references will be shared across instances.

Use `this.variableName` as suggested by dystroy or use `this.setName = function(newName)`. (Using this for variables is better, because it doesn't duplicate the functions for every object instance.)

But if you really don't want to expose the variables use this:

```
function Test(){
    var name;
    var id;

    this.setId = function(newId){
        id = newId; 
    }

    this.getId = function(newId){
        return  id;
    }

    this.setName = function(newName){
        name = newName; 
    }

    this.getName = function(newGuid){
        return name;    
    }
}
```

---

A workaround to share prototype functions without exposing variables directly is this:

```
(function () {
    var stores = [];
    var counter = 0;
    window.Test = function () {
        this.storeId = stores.length;
        stores.push({});
    }

    Test.prototype.setId = function (newId) {
        stores[this.storeId].id = newId;
    }
    Test.prototype.getId = function (newId) {
        return stores[this.storeId].id;
    }
    Test.prototype.setName = function (newName) {
        stores[this.storeId].name = newName;
    }
    Test.prototype.getName = function (newGuid) {
        return stores[this.storeId].name;
    }
})();
```

**Explanation:** The code is wrapped in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), ensuring that the variables can't be accessed from outside that function. Inside the IIFE we create a list of stores for our object instances. We then define our `Test` class and add the functions to the prototype.

Whenever a new instance is created we create a new store and append it to the list of stores. We also add a `storeId` to the instance, so that we can access the values in the instance store. Outside functions can access the storeId, but get any data from the store itself.

`stores[this.storeId]` always fetches the store for our object instance, which we then use similarly to `this`.

Comment: I don't want to use this, else the variables will be become public. I want the variables as private.

Comment: @user2007533 My solution does not expose the variables, I've added a code example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

But, in case I use the functions with this, as suggested by you, all the instances of Test Class will have these methods. It will bloat all the instance variable.

I want all the methods to be in Prototype class and the variables to be private.

Comment: @user2007533 I don't think memory will be an issue unless you a really huge number of these objects (tens of thousands). The prototype methods are shared among all object instances - so they will not be able to refer to different variables other than `this`. I have an idea for a workaround which I'll add to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Its working well. 

But being a beginner to JavaScript, I am not able to fully understand the code. :(. Can you please explain it.

Can you also tell from design perspective, how it would be to keep all getters using 'this' and setters and other methods as prototype methods.

Comment: @user2007533 Added an explanation. I don't see why you would mix `this.fn` and `this.prototype` since the only advantage of `this.fn` is that you can access local variables. But these won't be any good if you can't set them when using `this.prototype` for setters.

Comment: I want to do something like this:

`function Test(){
    var name;
  
  
    Test.prototype.setName = function(newName){
        name = newName; 
    }

    this.getName = function(newGuid){
           return name;    
    }


}`

As, this is working fine, meets the requirement of having private variables and lesser number of `this` functions to avoid memory consumtion. (Memory is critical in our project.)

Your solution is best, just its taking more time to digest it completely. :)

Comment: Ihave some addtional doubts with the code you have posted, which I got while playing with your code. I have added them to original question. Can you kindly help us in explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

I like Matt's approach. If the number of stores changes a lot, you can use an object instead of an array, and have som kind of dispose method that deletes stores[this.storeID]. Maybe there exists a way in Javascript to automatically call such a method/function during garbage collection, or when the objects leave the available scope(s)? Otherwise you have to call it before it's too late.

The inheritance issues can be caused by wrongly implemented inheritance.